# How to serialize my specific UTF format with MongoDB.Driver?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to have MongoDB.Driver serialize my date format to a DateTime.

The format of the data's datetime is like this:

> 2015-03-02T07:39:01.847

And the format of proper UTC is like this

> 2015-07-22T10:14:28+00:00

So I have data with a dot and milliseconds instead of stopping after the minute and adding the timezone.

Now, I have a `MyDate` property om my model `MyModel` as below.

```
public class MyModel
{
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately when parsing this the driver throws this error:

> System.FormatException
>   String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Any idea how to parse it properly to a `DateTime`?

Comment: MongoDB has a datetime type. Why don't you just store your datetime as that type and no formatting will be needed.

Comment: @i3arnon You mean changing the data itself? Unfortunately, I have no control over the data.

Comment: The data is probably already a DateTime type in MongoDB.

Comment: @i3arnon  Thanks I will try. Okay, BsonDatetime and BsonTimeStamp don't work.

Comment: When you dig up a document from mongo, what is the format of "MyDate" field in mongo? Is it a string? Sounds a bit like the stored documents have a string in them, and you are expecting automatic conversion to C# DateTime type. In that case a custom serialization might be in order.

Comment: @NukNukSan Thanks. It looks like `ISODate("2015-03-02T07:39:26.693Z")`. Where do I hook into the `MongoDB.Driver` API to perform custom serialization? Also see the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627240/how-to-convert-isodate-to-datetime.