# How to convert ISODate to DateTime?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In a collection I have IsoDates stored as follows:

```
 SubmitDateTime" : ISODate("2015-03-02T07:39:05.463Z")
```

Now I want to map this property to `MyModel` with the following property:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public DateTime SubmitDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

And then map it as follows:

```
GetCollection<MyModel>("collection_name").Find(myQuery).ToListAsync();
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
>   The value -9223372036854775808 for the BsonDateTime MillisecondsSinceEpoch is outside therange that can be converted to a .NET DateTime

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

PS I originally converted string representations of this format "2015-03-30T10:50:01.813" to the `IsoDate` with this script in the Mongo shell:

```
var cursor = db.collection_name.find()
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var doc = cursor.next();
  db.collection_name.update({_id : doc._id}, {$set : {SubmitDateTime : new Date(doc.SubmitDateTime)}})
}
```

Perhaps an improvement can be made there.

Comment: This should just happen naturally as it is the default mapper. Your error suggests that something went wrong when you converted, since the value you specify in your error would mean that many milliseconds in the past from epoch 1970-01-01. And that is quite a long time ago. 292 million years before that date to be precise

Comment: @BlakesSeven. Thanks. Do you see anything wrong with `ISODate("2015-03-02T07:39:05.463Z")`?

Comment: No, but can you produce a case where you are absolutely certain that particular date is causing the problem? That should not be hard. And a clear and reproducable case would help your question immensely. So show a single document, and show code to find that document that also results in the same error.